# How to add list of data .txt into C program?

Tags: c

Good evening people,

please don't blame me...  I need a little advice. I need to make a list of, let's say 100 names and work with them in my C program (filter them, print those beggining with letter i choose ...., doesn't matter).
Unfortunately I've got no idea how to name this "problem" and I can't find manual.  It should be using something like this  `<filename.txt`

Glad for any advice

Thank you!

**INSTRUCTIONS (just additional info):**
Database of names are text data. Each line is equal to 1 name (maximum of 100 characters). There is no ordinal organization (like alphabet).

In this piece of code, names were being read from program arguments, all in all I need to read these names from `.txt`

**Restriction:**
`fgets`, `fopen`, `fclose`, `fscanf` are unfortunately prohibited.

```
int i;
char firstLetter;

printf("What name r u looking for?\n");
scanf("%c", &firstLetter);

printf("Search: %c\n", firstLetter);

for(i=1;i<argc;i++)
{
           if (argv[i][0] == firstLetter)
    {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }

}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: so you need to know how to open up a text file and read it line by line into memory?

Comment: Use `fgets`. like `char line[100+2]; while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)){ if(line[0] == firstLetter) ...`. When using standard input, `"%c"` --> `"%c%*c"`, `fp` -->  `stdin`.

Comment: Your question *suggests* you want to redirect input from a file, instead of processing the program arguments. In that case please use `fgets()`. If you read from the standard stream `stdin` there is no need to open a file.

Comment: fgets, fopen, fclose, fscanf are unfortunately prohibited. Forgot to tell you guys. Im sorry

Comment: So `char line[100+1]; while(scanf("%100s", line)!=EOF){...`

Comment: @yano Yes, as you say :)

Comment: But the question says "It should be using something like this `<filename.txt`". That goes to `stdin` stream, which is already open.

Comment: ... so you don't need to use `fopen`, `fclose`, `fscanf`. You can use `scanf` as in your code sample.

Comment: @WeatherVane Im sorry, this is greek to me. Data have to be taken from stdin. Example of searching for name: $ ./proj1 <names.txt

Comment: You posted:  It should be using something like this `<filename.txt` in the question. That means you run the program like `myprog <filename.txt`. The content of that text file, is directed to the `stdin` stream, which is already open. So you can use `scanf` which takes input from `stdin` as you did in your code sample.